# Why does division "/" and floored division "//" operators in python gives different results for divisions with a remainder = 0?

Tags: python, integer-division

When dividing somewhat large integers with numbers that divides them, I get different results from division `/` and floored division `//`.

for instance:

```
In [1]: a = 123456789012345678

In [2]: int(a/2)
Out[2]: 61728394506172840

In [3]: a//2
Out[3]: 61728394506172839
```

clearly 2|a, and out[3] is the correct answer, so why the inconsistency from the division operator? what is going on? and, How to make `/` behave correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/` is the floating division operator, thus your integer is stored into a float type. This type cannot store exactly every value, only approximations, see:

```
>>> a = 123456789012345678
>>> a/2
6.172839450617284e+16
```

You lose the last digit... `123456789012345678` approximately equals to 6.172839450617284 * 10^16.
Look what happens for "huge" numbers:

```
>>> float(1234512345123451234512345)
1.2345123451234512e+24
```

Floats are basically scientific notation with fixed size mantissa.

While `//` is the integer division operator, and integer type (in Python) is of arbitrary precision (only in the domain of integers):

```
>>> 2**1000
10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376
```

Comment: So in case of big numbers where  b ∤ a, using both integer division `//` and modulo operator `%` should that preserve all information?

Comment: @topcat yes. `(x//b)*b + (x%b)=x`

Answer (score -3):

Your first calculation `/` does division on an double floating point value that can store bigger numbers but is less accurate. The second division `//` is performed on integer which has no rounding issues in this case.

Comment: No Python uses arbitrary precision for integers...

Comment: Hm, I checked before posting and found something about 64 bit integers... maybe i did not read careful enough so that there are cases when its different...